# SED and/or awk help required

Tags: sed, awk

I am using openvms but have access to versions of aWk and /or sed on this platform. Wondered if anyone can help with a text file processing job.

My file looks like

```
START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|XYZ
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
11:31|BID|12.5|ASK|12.7
11:34|BID|12.6|ASK|12.7
END-OF-DATA
START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|ABC
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
11:40|BID|.245|ASK|.248
11:34|BID|.246|ASK|.249
END-OF-DATA
```

Basically I want to pre-pend the `BID/ASK` data records with the `Stock ID` so the above file should look like

```
START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|XYZ
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
XYZ|11:31|BID|12.5|ASK|12.7
XYZ|11:34|BID|12.6|ASK|12.7
END-OF-DATA
START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|ABC
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
ABC|11:40|BID|.245|ASK|.248
ABC|11:34|BID|.246|ASK|.249
END-OF-DATA
```

Can any one help ?

Comment: Make sure you accept an answer that helped you resolve your question. You can do so by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} /^Stock/{S=$2}  /BID|ASK/{print S,$0}' file
```

**Explanation** (with thanks to Olivier Dulac)

It updates "S" variable each time it encounters a line stating with "Stock", and then prepends S to lines CONTAINING "BID" or "ASK" (using | as a separator for reading and for outputting).

Comment: +1 elegant. (it updates "S" variable each time it encounters a line stating with "Stock", and then prepend S to lines CONTAINING "BID" or "ASK" (using | as a separator for reading and for outputting)

Comment: Olivier: Thank you. I was about to add a description - with your consent, I'll add yours into the body of my answer for all to see.

Comment: as you wish :)  [I should have let you time to add it... I did it just in case you wouldn't ^^]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==2{pre=$2}NF>2{$0=pre FS $0}7' file
```

it works for the given example.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk '/Stock ID/{s=$2}/BID|ASK/{$0=s FS $0}1' FS=\| file

START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|XYZ
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
XYZ|11:31|BID|12.5|ASK|12.7
XYZ|11:34|BID|12.6|ASK|12.7
END-OF-DATA
START-OF-DATA
Stock ID|ABC
START-TIME 11:30
END_TIME 12:30
ABC|11:40|BID|.245|ASK|.248
ABC|11:34|BID|.246|ASK|.249
END-OF-DATA
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I have all the answers I need now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/Stock ID/h;/BID|ASK/{G;s/(.*)\n.*\|(.*)/\2|\1/}' file
```

Save the `Stock ID` in the hold space and prepend it to records containing `BID` or `ASK`.